# How to set up lastrow selecting range in vba

Tags: vba

Trying to set up last-row between ("B4:B17") and kept on getting an error(APPLICATION DEFINE OR OBJECT DEFINE ERROR), is there any other way i can set up last-row selecting range or what i am doing wrong in this code

```
 sub try()
   dim lastrow as long
   lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("D4:D17" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Range.find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) method to find the last row.

In case all cells are empty, you should use `On error resume next` to suppress an error

```
Sub try()
    Dim lastrow as long
    On Error Resume Next
    lastrow = [B4:B17].Find("*", [B4], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: it doesn't work cause i have a value in row 18 but want last row to count till 17. so this code still counting till 18

Comment: @user3795861 For me, the above code does work. You can see it here: http://ge.tt/1i3pwjJ2/v/0

Comment: ya it do work, but can i show you one more question http://superuser.com/questions/936471/how-can-i-create-click-function-between-a1-to-a10-prompt-inputbox-for-user-to-en

Answer (score 0):

Actually i figured it out but someone please let me know if there is any other ways..

```
  lastrow = Range("B17").End(xlUp).Row
```