# How can i create click function between A1 to A10 prompt inputbox for user to enter numbers in vba

Tags: worksheet-function, vba

I am trying to create input box for selecting range (A1 to A10), every time when i click any cells between 1 to 10, i want to prompt input box to enter numbers.
That's what i did but it's not working properly, any suggestion..Also i have my code under THISWORKBOOK instead module1.

```
  Function Find_Blank_Row() As Double

       Dim QtyInput As Double
       Dim BlankRow As Long
       BlankRow = Range("A10").End(xlUp).Row
       QtyInput = InputBox("Enter today expense")
       Cells(BlankRow, 1).Font.Bold = True
       Cells(BlankRow, 1).Value = QtyInput
  End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you're planning, you should lookup Excel events topic. In this case probably Worksheet_SelectionChange or Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick. Below example is for worksheet module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim PopupRange As Range
    Set PopupRange = Me.Range("A1:A10")

    If Not Intersect(PopupRange, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Dim InputCell As Range
        Set InputCell = PopupRange.Cells(PopupRange.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        InputCell.Font.Bold = True
        InputCell.Value = InputBox("Enter today expense")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I added activecell.value = InputCell to paste the value in the cell but its not doing it and also what does offest(1) means what if i wanna use range E instead of A